# Is there any issues after upgrading native Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell XPS 13 developer edition?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dell

I've just bought Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (Sputnik 3). Default version of Ubuntu is 12.04, and obviously I don't want to stuck with almost 2 years old distribution.

I just wandering is it save to upgrade to latest (13.10) Ubuntu? Is there any know issues I supposed take under consideration before upgrading? If so is there any know solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally safe, you must backup your data first and then do the upgrade or clean install (which I recommend because there has been an Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04 and the new 13.10 and I'm not really sure if it will let you upgrade straight away so it will be much faster to clean install).

PS: If you are upgrading through terminal:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: and what with extra drivers. I'm seening them for dispaly/touch etc..? Can I download them from somewhere?

Is there any other problems after clean instalation?

Comment: You will see everything working out of the box, this is not Windows you are talking about :)